# Select rows using query builder in CakePHP based on the same end association but different relation to it

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

What I want to do is to get all rows related with user_id but in a different way. 
First condition is to get all Books that are related with the User via Resources table where user_id is stored (in other words - Books owned by the User). Second condition is to get all Books that are related with the User through the Cities model again which is stored in the Resources table as well (Books that belong to Cities owned by the User).

I tried really a lot of things and I simply cannot make this two conditions work because I use JOIN (tried different combinations of innerJoinWith and leftJoinWith) on the same "end" model (User).

What I've done so far:

```
$userBooks = $this->Books->find()
                ->leftJoinWith("Resources.Users")
                ->leftJoinWith("Cities.Resources.Users")
                ->where(["Resources.Users" => 1])
                ->orWhere(["Cities.Resources.Users" => 1])
                ->all();
```

This of course does not work, but I hope you get the point about what I'm trying to achieve. The best what I was able to get with trying different approaches is the result of **only one JOIN statement** what is logical.
Basically, this can be separated into 2 parts which gives expected result (but I do not prefer it because I want it done with one query of course):

```
$userBooks = $this->Books->find()
                ->innerJoinWith("Resources.Users", function($q) {
                    return $q->where(["Users.id" => 1]);
                })
                ->all();
$userBooks2 = $this->Books->find()
                ->innerJoinWith("Cities.Resources.Users", function($q) {
                    return $q->where(["Users.id" => 1]);
                })
                ->all();
```

Also, before this I created an SQL script which works well and result is like expected:

```
SELECT books.id FROM books, cities, users_resources WHERE 
        (users_resources.resource_id = books.resource_id AND users_resources.user_id = 1) 
        OR 
        (users_resources.resource_id = cities.resource_id AND books.city_id = cities.id AND users_resources.user_id = 1)
```

This query works and I want to transfer it into ORM styled query in CakePHP to get both Books that are owned by the user and the ones that are connected with the User via Cities. I want somehow to separate these joins to individually filter data like I did in the SQL query.

**EDIT**

I've tried @ndm solution but the result is the same as where there is only 1 association (User) - I was still able to get data based on only one join statement (second one was ignored). Due to the fact I had to move on, I ended up with

```
    $userBooks = $this->Books->find()
        ->innerJoinWith("Cities.Resources.Users"‌​)
        ->where(["Users.id" => $userId])
        ->union($this->Books->find()
            ->innerJoinWith("Resour‌​ces.Users")
            ->where([‌​"Users.id" => $userId])
        )
        ->all();
```

which outputs correct result but not in very effective way (by union of 2 queries). I would really like to know the best way to approach this as this is a very common case (**filtering by related model (user) that is associated with other models**).

Answer (score 1):

The ORM (specifically the eager loader) doesn't allow joining the same alias multiple times.

This can be worked around in various ways, the most simple one probaly being creating a separate association with a unique alias. For example in your `ResourcesTable`, create another association to `Users` with a different alias, say `Users2`, like:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Users2', [
    'className' => 'Users'
]);
```

Then you can use that association in the second `leftJoinWith()`, and apply the conditions accordingly:

```
$this->Books
    ->find()
    ->leftJoinWith('Resources.Users')
    ->leftJoinWith('Cities.Resources.Users2')
    ->where(['Users.id' => 1])
    ->orWhere(['Users2.id' => 1])
    ->group('Books.id')
    ->all();
```

And don't forget to group your books to avoid duplicate results.

You could also create the joins manually using `leftJoin()` or `join()` instead, where you can define the aliases on your own (or don't use any at all) so that there are no conflicts, for more complex queries that can be a tedious task though.

You could also use your two separate queries as subqueries for conditions on `Books`, or even create a union query from them, which however might perform worse...

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)**
- **[CakePHP Issues > Improve association data fetching](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9499)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know how I didn't come up to this solution by myself (creating another association) but I will try it out. However, what first comes to my mind is this: what if I had more deeply nested relations - would I need to create new assoc. ("Users3", "Users4") every time? For more complex situations it doesn't look flexible and "join" methods over complicate this pretty simple things. I come from the Laravel framework and there you have methods like "whereHas()" that accept relation and closure that allows you to filter. CakePHP needs something like this obviously.

Comment: I've tried your solution but the result is the same as where there is only 1 association (User) - I was still able to get data based on only one join statement (second one was ignored). Due to the fact I had to move on, I ended up with `$userBooks = $this->Books->find()->innerJoinWith("Cities.Resources.Users")->where(["Users.id" => $userId])->union($this->Books->find()->innerJoinWith("Resources.Users")->where(["Users.id" => $userId]))->all();` which outputs correct result but not in very effective way (by union of 2 queries). I would really like to know the best way to approach this.

Comment: Well, I don't know what exactly you're doing, I can only tell you that using additional associations as in the shown example does generally work. The CakePHP ORM produces very different SQL for it's matching functionality, that is joins instead of subqueries as conditions, hence it requires unique aliases. You could use subqueries similar to Laravel too, but you'd have to build them manually. As for the alias problem, you may want to add a feature request [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

Comment: @techquestions See also **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9499**, that ticket addresses your issue.